# Write and read php object in a text file?

Tags: php, file, fopen, fread

I want to write a php object in a text file. The php object is like that

```
 $obj = new stdClass();
 $obj->name = "My Name";
 $obj->birthdate = "YYYY-MM-DD";
 $obj->position = "My position";
```

I want to write this $obj in a text file. The text file is located in this path

```
$filePath = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."note".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."notice.txt"
```

I want a simple way to write this object into the text file and want to read the file to get the properties as I defined. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the following code for write php object in the text file...

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->name = "My Name";
$obj->birthdate = "YYYY-MM-DD";
$obj->position = "My position";

$objData = serialize( $obj);
$filePath = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."note".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."notice.txt";
if (is_writable($filePath)) {
    $fp = fopen($filePath, "w"); 
    fwrite($fp, $objData); 
    fclose($fp);
}
```

To read the text file to get the properties as you defined...

```
$filePath = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."note".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."notice.txt";
if (file_exists($filePath)){
    $objData = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $obj = unserialize($objData);           
    if (!empty($obj)){
        $name = $obj->name;
        $birthdate = $obj->birthdate;
        $position = $obj->position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I like this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is_writable($filePath) did not work for me, because it includes the file. My path was actually writable, but is_writable was only true without filename.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `serialize()` before saving it to the file and then `unserialize()` to get the whole `$obj` available to you:

```
 $obj = new stdClass();
 $obj->name = "My Name";
 $obj->birthdate = "YYYY-MM-DD";
 $obj->position = "My position";
 $objtext = serialize($obj);
 //write to file
```

Then later you can unserialize():

```
 $obj = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));
 echo $obj->birthdate;//YYYY-MM-DD
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead we can use following method to write whole object in the file.

```
$fp = fopen('D:\file_name.txt', 'w');        
fwrite($fp, print_r($obj, true));
fclose($fp);
```

So, inside print_r() function we need to pass object and true parameter which will return the information to fwrite() function rather than printing it.

Comment: How can you read the `print_r` results again?

Comment: @Koorosh Once you write the object in the file you can check your desired value(s) in it easily