# How do I cache and reuse a copy of GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response for debugging purposes?

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I'm processing a large API response that comes as `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response`. While debugging and profiling my script, I'd like to eliminate the varying network and API server response times.

My idea was to simply save a copy of the JSON that the server responds with into a text file, and keep reading it from the local filesystem until I'm done. Since I can't neither inject the JSON into the curl handler, nor [`serialize()` it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681090/write-and-read-php-object-in-a-text-file), I'd have to save the whole `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response`. But it contains some streams, which it later tries to read and fails.

I have tried serializing and immediately unserializing just to see if it works (it doesn't):

- [src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:106](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/d2db8f533d50f1b60a17bcada73b85ebc78965dd/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php#L106)

  ```
  if (!$easy->response || $easy->errno) {
      return self::finishError($handler, $easy, $factory);
  }
  $temporaryCopy = serialize($easy->response);
  $easy->response = unserialize($temporaryCopy);
  ```
- [src/Handler/CurlHandler.php:40](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/d2db8f533d50f1b60a17bcada73b85ebc78965dd/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php#L40)

  ```
  curl_exec($easy->handle);
  $temporaryCopy = serialize($easy->handle);
  $easy->handle = unserialize($temporaryCopy);
  ```

The above doesn't work. Before I continue fighting the framework, is there an out-of-the box way to get it done?